# Multiple and/or statements in one line Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In order to keep my jenkins file concise, I am trying to write to sets of if statements in one line. Statements go like this

```
stage(execute) {
    if((branch = master && action = apply && selectedEnv == "prod-pci" || selectedEnv == "prod-pci-dr") || (branch =! master && action = apply && selectedEnv =! "prod*")) 
    
    {
    command
    }
}
```

but its not working. Can someone please tell how can this be achieved in a concise way? or do I have to do it write two stages?

Comment: Equals is `==` not equals is `!=`. Your if statement has a whole collection of wrong

Comment: You have 2 assignments in the conditions (`=`) which will resolve to whatever `master` and `apply` are assigned to. The conditional operator is not `=!` but `!=`. Anyway, readability should be the goal.

Answer (score 0):

So below solution worked.

```
 stage('Terraform Apply') {
     if(("$Actions" == "Deploy" && params.Branch == "origin/master" && targetEnv.contains("prod")) || ("$Actions" == "Deploy" && params.Branch != "origin/master" && !targetEnv.contains("prod"))){

some action.

}
}
```